# Processing Continuous Callbacks on key holding

Tags: callback, processing

I want to implement the navigational system in my Processing project. If user (that navigates the object) wants to turn left, he hits the 'a' button. Here is my callback function on keyPressed:

```java
void keyPressed() {
 ...
 if(key == 'a') { ship.plainAngle -= 0.1; }
 else if(key == 'd') { ship.plainAngle += 0.1; }
}
```

What I want to avoid is spamming the 'a' key in order to make 90 degrees turn left. I tried increasing the value that affects it directly (0.1) but it made it look laggy. I heard that there is a possibility in processing to make continuous callbacks while user keeps holding the key. As I found out using callback function `keyPressed` should work out but it doesn't work for me. The code in callback function executes only once. I don't know how to solve that problem.

Comment: Not enough information.

How are you setting up the callback? What UI library are you using?

Comment: I use pure Processing without any library. I set up callback function in my main project file by declaring it as I presented above.

Comment: In the future, please post a [mcve] instead of a disconnected snippet like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `boolean` variable to keep track of whether the `a` key (or any other key you care about) is currently held down. Set it to `true` in the `mousePressed()` function, and set it to `false` in the `mouseReleased()` function. Then in the `draw()` function, you can check that variable and do something if the key is currently being pressed.

Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on keyboard input in Processing available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/input). Check out the section on handling multiple key presses for the approach I just outlined.